# Separate street name from house number?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In the table I have a list of customer address, in the `street` field I want to copy the street number into `house_number` field.

For Example, street Name:

- 8 Blah Road
- 604 Blah Road
- 20A Blah Street
- 10-15 Blah Lane
- 42/5 Blah Street

So the house number would be: 8, 604, 20A, 10-15, 42/5

Is it possible to that in SQL Query or PHP?

Comment: In all of those examples, the house number is the first "word" (up to the first whitespace). Is this true for all your data?

Comment: split on the first space char?

Comment: How many records? Is there a definite pattern you can apply reliably to every record?

Comment: And every house has a number in this country? What about houses with a name rather than a number?

Comment: What about P.O. Boxes (or their international standard)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be something like below:

Break the string from first whitespace.

```
 update table set house_number=SUBSTRING_INDEX(street," ");
```

Note: In this case the house number is always first "word" in street value

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could write some PHP you could update each row based on a Regular Expression?

The RegEx would look something like:

(\d+\w*)\s(.*)

And I'd expect $1 to be the house number and $2 to be the street name.